# Small String Hash Function

Tags: c++, string, hash, hashcode

I have a string that will be from anywhere from length 1 to length 5 and need to hash it with good performance and minimal collisions.  Any suggestions?  (I don't need security)

Comment: into how big a number? And is it an ansi or unicode string?

Comment: How long should the hash be?

Comment: More info is needed for an answer. If the set of strings is known at compile time, see Paul Evan's answer. Otherwise, all "mainstream" hash functions will perform reasonably well (or equally bad) for such short strings. I would use a multiply-add hash such as djb2 or sdbm, since they're easy, fast, and only 3 lines of code. I wouldn't use something like murmurhash or cityhash which works on 32 or 64 bit words, if your expected input strings are usually only 32 bits or less -- rather have a byte-by-byte hash iterate a few times more.

Comment: You might not even need to hash at all if you can fit the string into your hash size, and you don't need to obscure the original string.

Comment: The hash length needs to grow with input, I was planning on using an unordered_map and just letting they STL take care of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your scenario, you may have certain needs for what kind of hash that you need. But if all you need is something to separate them, then `std::hash()` does spring to mind...

Another option would be something like:

```
long long hash(const std::string &val) {
    long long hash = 0;
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&hash), val.c_str(), std::min(sizeof(hash), val.length());
    return hash;
}
```

Apologies for any mistypes in the above code, it has not been compiled or tested. This has minimal collisions (none), I would guess pretty good performance, and not-so-great quality. By quality I mean separation of values that are near each other and usage of entire key space.

There are also of course the whole range of regular cryptographic hash functions to choose from, but I take it from your question that these are not what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have linux?  Try `/bin/gperf` it generate a perfect hash function from a key set.